# Post XML String in SOAP message

Tags: iphone, xml, soap

I want some help friends,
I want to Post XML string in SOAP message in iOS sdk.
Is it possible to do this?
If yes, Please give me some sample code for that. otherwise advice me alternative way to do this.
Please help me to come out from this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<postCourseUsage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xml><?xml version="1.0"?><CU><ULID>admin</ULID><CID>myOwn</CID><CURS><CUR><CN>Home</CN><USG><CUSG>2</CUSG><SD>12-Jul-2011 12:41:42</SD></USG></CUR></CURS></CU></xml>
</postCourseUsage>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<postCourseUsage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xml>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;CU&gt;&lt;ULID&gt;admin&lt;/ULID&gt;&lt;CID&gt;myOwn&lt;/CID&gt;&lt;CURS&gt;&lt;CUR&gt;&lt;CN&gt;Home&lt;/CN&gt;&lt;USG&gt;&lt;CUSG&gt;2&lt;/CUSG&gt;&lt;SD&gt;12-Jul-2011 12:41:42&lt;/SD&gt;&lt;/USG&gt;&lt;/CUR&gt;&lt;/CURS&gt;&lt;/CU&gt;</xml>
</postCourseUsage>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using this code i can pass xml string as argument in soap message and on the server side it will interprete it as XML.

Comment: note: you are really only posting a string, which is correctly XML-encoded (escaped); all 'normal' web-service clients support this per default.