# How to send XML as String to Soap Action?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, web-services

I have Soap Action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<From_Iphone xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<MessageText>string</MessageText>
<user_id>int</user_id>
<patientID>int</patientID>
<ReplyToMsgId>int</ReplyToMsgId>
<UserContacts>string</UserContacts>
</From_Iphone>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in this i would like to send the

```
 MessageText =@"Testing";
patientID= 10;
user_id= 20;
ReplyToMsgId=1;
UserContacts = @"< Contacts > < Contact >< id > 5 < /id > < name > Kiran< /name > < gr_id >11 < /gr_id> < /Contact> < Contact>< id>8< /id> < name>najeer< /name>< gr_id>25< /gr_id>< /Contact>< /Contacts>";
```

I am passing the  UserContacts as string but i am not able to hit the server. Please give me a solution for passing an xml as String..
Thank You...

Comment: Check this....
It may help...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283038/image-transfer-between-iphone-application-and-server/7283172#7283172

Comment: Check this....
It may help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283038/image-transfer-between-iphone-application-and-server/7283172#7283172

Comment: Do you actually have spaces before and after `<` and `>` in the xml?  At least don't do that.

Comment: no, i dont have spaces in actual data.

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection?  Show the code you are using to actually set up the request and make the connection.

Comment: gothrough this post it may helps u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660921/post-xml-string-in-soap-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  tag for this.
In  tag u have to put Your xmlstring. 
The string between the  will not be parsed. I think Your problem will be solved.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

fallow the above link it will help You

Comment: Link is now broken, maybe this one works now https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_cdatasection.asp

Comment: Link is now broken, maybe this one works now https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_cdatasection.asp